# Align decimals in a list of doubles in Java

Tags: java, alignment, double, decimal

Here's the code section:

```
    System.out.println("The values of pi from term " + (userNum - 9) + " to term " + userNum + " are:");        
        for (int x = 1; x < userNum; x++) 
            {
                if (x % 2 == 1)
                    sum = sum + (4.0/(2 * x - 1));
                else
                    sum = sum - (4.0/(2 * x - 1));
            System.out.println("Term " + (x) + ": " + sum);
            }
```

And here's the output:

```
The values of pi from term 2 to term 11 are:
Term 1: 4.0
Term 2: 2.666666666666667
Term 3: 3.466666666666667
Term 4: 2.8952380952380956
Term 5: 3.3396825396825403
Term 6: 2.9760461760461765
Term 7: 3.2837384837384844
Term 8: 3.017071817071818
Term 9: 3.2523659347188767
Term 10: 3.0418396189294032
```

Term 10's decimal needs to align with the others. How can that be done in Java? Thanks.

Comment: Use `System.out.printf(...)` or `String.format(....)`. The API will show you how these are used.

Comment: I have tried printf; it doesn't seem to work well unless it's used with an actual value. Is there a way to do printf with a variable (in this case, "sum")?

I haven't tried String.format; I read about it in the API, but I'm only lately come to programming and very new to Java -- I don't really understand how to apply that to my particular code. 

Thanks Jeffrey and Hovercraft.

Comment: `"I have tried printf; it doesn't seem to work well unless it's used with an actual value."`: I don't understand your statement here. This ***is*** the best solution. If you've tried it then you should show us how you've tried it and what your out put is. String.format works the same as printf except it returns a String that can later be printed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That is an answer.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I though it for a minute and convert it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.printf` resembles (but is not) the C printf method. You can use it do to something like:

```
int spaces = (int)Math.log10(Math.abs(userNum)) + 1;
String myFormat = "Term %" + spaces +"d: %.10f\n";

//inside the for loop
System.out.printf(myFormat , x, sum);
```

Edited: You can use %2d to have a number using 2 spaces, if the number is bigger then it will use more spaces.

More info:

- [PrintStream‌​](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (search for printf method)

Comment: @Luigi, I am adapting it for the program. Thanks for pointing the way.

Comment: Don't worry, that's the purpose of the answers, solve the real problem or serve as a base to solve it.

Comment: @user1519533 I've edited my answer again, based in the spaces for the back (only in case you need it like that).

Comment: I see I misspelled your name... Thanks for the update. I've played with it a little and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang), you could use the `StringUtils` class to accomplish what you need:

```
System.out.println("Term " + 
    StringUtils.leftPad("" + x, (userNum.length() - x.length()), ' ')
      + ": " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to add space after `Term` depending on the number of digits of `x`:

```
    int j = String.valueOf(x).length();
    String sp = "";
    while( j++ < String.valueOf(userNum).length() )
        sp += " ";
    System.out.printf("Term %s %d : %.15f\n", sp, x, sum);
```

Comment: After seeing your answer with the sp *trick*, I've edited mine. You should learn to use `printf` before using it in a comment/post.

Comment: Also, did you know that you can get the number of digits in a number (inside the scope of long numbers) by using `(int)Math.log10(Math.abs(longVar)) + 1;` (even faster than converting the number to a String).

Comment: Thanks JR. I'll play with it.

Comment: OP, as mentioned, use `printf` properly with `%2d` or %3d if `userNum > 100`

Comment: Ok, answer edited based in that, I didn't pay attention to that fact.